# Do Bunkers give increased range to units inside in SCII?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran, starcraft

When units are inside a bunker, does this bunker give them additional range? I believe in SC and/or SC:BW they gave units an increased range. Is this true in either?

Basically: **Do bunkers give range benefits to units inside?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which units should I put in bunkers?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38515/which-units-should-i-put-in-bunkers)

Comment: Not even close to a duplicate. This question is asking what benefits do bunkers give to units inside of them. I'm not asking what units I should put in them.

Comment: @Sorean the only relevance relies in your answer, not the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both games units inside the bunker get a flat +1 range.

In SC:BW they can sometimes also get range boosts because of how angles worked in the game. For example, Marines (4 range) inside a bunker can hit Range upgraded Dragoons (6 range) unless those Dragoons are positioned properly.

Comment: Cool, thanks! You may want to add a source or two but overall nice answer.